# OIDC - Access token expiration issue when browser window/tab is idle for around a day

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, chromium

I am using OIDC to get an access token that has a lifetime of 60 mins. I am using oidc-client.js library which makes periodic calls to refresh the access token every 30 mins.

This works well but the problem is if I keep the browser tab/window idle for around a day the periodic refresh calls stop and when I try to take any action on the application the API endpoint gives an unauthorized error.

My suspicion is that chrome puts the window in an idle state that prevents the periodic refresh calls.

One of the possible solutions is to reload the browser window if I get an unauthorized error, but I am looking if any solution exists without having to reload the window.

EDIT: The auth server we use currently does not have support for refresh tokens. But even if we were to use refresh tokens, that would not solve the problem, I believe. Refresh tokens would also have some kind of expiry. And after a certain period of inactivity, the refresh tokens would expire.

Notes:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture/#giving-back-memory
https://blog.chromium.org/2021/12/chrome-windows-performance-improvements-native-window-occlusion.html

Comment: When you say that you "make periodic refresh calls", is that using a refresh_token that was issued under offline_access scope? You need to store the refresh token somewhere more persistent than in-memory. Don't put it directly in a cookie, but either on the server or maybe local storage if you don't have a web server session.

Comment: Can't you wait with the access token refresh until you actually need it? Or is the refresh token also short-lived?

Comment: The auth server we have does not currently support refresh tokens. But even if we were to use refresh tokens, that would not solve the problem, I believe.
Refresh tokens would also have some kind of expiry. And after a certain period of inactivity, the refresh tokens would expire.

Comment: refresh tokens typically should have an expiry that makes sense for these use-cases. So a good auth server will let your refresh tokens last days or weeks. It's not logically to require polling to keep an authentication alive